# Pandas filter MultiIndex on part of MultiIndex using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I want to filter a DataFrame using only 2 levels of a 3-level MultiIndex. Is there a way cant find a way to do that with `.loc`?

The only way I managed to do that is the following:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(1,'a','x')
,(1,'a','y')
,(1,'b','z')
,(1,'b','x')
,(2,'c','y')
,(2,'c','z')
,(2,'a','x')
,(2,'a','y')
,(3,'b','z')
,(3,'b','x')
,(3,'c','y')
,(3,'c','z')]), 
data=[20,26,43,20,65,40,87,41,84,50,5,54])

f=[(2, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (3, 'c')]

df=df.reset_index(level=2).loc[f].reset_index().set_index(['level_0','level_1','level_2'])
```

resulting `df` is:

|  |  |  | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| level_0 | level_1 | level_2 |  |
| 2 | a | x | 87 |
|  |  | y | 41 |
| 3 | b | z | 84 |
|  |  | x | 50 |
|  | c | z | 5 |
|  |  | x | 54 |

What I want is to be able to do something like `df.loc[(f,slice(None))]` to make the code a bit less complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think `f` is not appropriate example becuz a and b do not overlap in 2 and 3

Let's take a from 1 and only b from 3 (becuz 1 also has b)

```
idx = [(1, 'a'), (3, 'b')]
df[df.index.droplevel(2).isin(idx)]
```

result:

```
            0
1   a   x   20
        y   26
3   b   z   84
        x   50
```

Comment: Hi - I dont follow "I think f is not an appropriate example" - I can not be proscriptive about how the filter arrives so I cant change the inputs just to fit the solution - or am i missing something?

Comment: Of course, my code can also be applied to 2 and 3(`f`). 1 and 3 are more appropriate examples. Your consent is not important. I made an example with 1,3 for someone to see. It can solve your problem and show others a more appropriate example.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you still can achieve that, you just have to structure your tuple correctly inside `loc`.

```
df.loc[([2, 3], ["a", "b"], ), :]
```

Output:

```
        0
2 a x  87
    y  41
3 b z  84
    x  50
```

Comment: Hi - this is not a preference for me because my "f" arrives as a list of tuples not a tuple of lists and restructuring my starting point does not make my code simpler. Thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is to use [`get_locs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_locs.html#pandas.MultiIndex.get_locs) the output of which can be used to locate using `iloc`. Basically `get_locs` returns a sequence of integers based on the index passed.

```
df.iloc[np.ravel([df.index.get_locs(t) for t in f])]
```

Output:

```
        0
2 a x  87
    y  41
3 b z  84
    x  50
```

Comment: Hi  - no this doesnt work because its selecting on level 1 and then level 2 not the explicit values in the filter - consider `f=[(2, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (3, 'c')]` it returns values for `(2,'c'`)`

Comment: @JohnnieL you are right, I updated answer with another way.

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [select_rows](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select.select_rows) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) - your data might need to be sorted to avoid a Performance warning:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.sort_index().select_rows(f)
        0
2 a x  87
    y  41
3 b x  50
    z  84
  c y   5
    z  54
```